# Stretch border beyond div & shadow on image

Tags: css, image

I have two questions, hope its not a problem putting them in one post.

**Question1**
I have a border I want to stretch across the full screen but cant get it to work. I have tried width: 150%, which is okay for the right side, but leaves the left as before. I then added margin:- 100% but that naturally caused issues with items with the div. My code is below. Also im guessing the code I tried would be considered a hack? I am trying not to get into that habit.

```
#border{
border-top: thick double #000;
border-bottom: thick double #000;
padding: 1% 0 1% 0;
margin-top: 3%;
margin-bottom: 3%;
}
#wrapper{   
max-width: 1200px;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}
#content{
margin-top: -3%;
}

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="border">
            <!--some small images-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Question2** I am trying to add a jagged edge with a shadow to the top of a div, I have created the image of the jagged edge and tried using the css3 shadow effect but with no success can someone please advise?

Comment: would be nice to attach a picture of "jagged edge with a shadow to the top of a div"

Comment: The code you supplied is stretching the border 100% of the page fine, I am not seeing the issue there. And I am not really sure what you mean about the jagged edge, you haven't included an image or any code for that.

Comment: i have sorted the jagged edge just as suggested by roman the great. The border does stretch 100% until i zoom out beyond 1200px, where my wrapper stops the border. I would like the border to go right across the page no matter how far I zoom out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your #border is inside your #wrapper with max-width:1200px so it's normal it will stop at the 1200-mark. Change the HTML to

```
<div id="border">
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">
        <!--some small images-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>​
```

and work from there.

Search Google for *CSS3 box-shadow* for your second problem, lots of examples there!